# Parallel transport of global sections and Riemannian curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, curvature

A, perhaps, naive question from an algebraist/combinatorialist teaching differential geometry. Originally asked on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850799/parallel-transport-on-sections-and-riemannian-curvature) but didn't receive a single comment in 3 days.

Consider a (real) smooth manifold $M$, a (real, finite rank) vector bundle $E$ on $M$ and a connection $\nabla:\Gamma(TM)\times\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)$. Let $X$ be a vector field on $M$. For simplicity I will assume that for some $t_0>0$ we have a flow $\theta:(-t_0,t_0)\times M\to M$ with infinitesimal generator $X$ although I believe the below can also be worded in terms of local flows. For a point $p\in M$ we have an integral curve of $\gamma_p:(-t_0,t_0)\to M$ of $X$ given by $\gamma_p(t)=\theta_t(p)$. We may consider the parallel transport map along this curve $P_t:E_p\to E_{\theta_t(p)}$.

Now, my first point is that it is easy to turn $P_t$ into a linear operator $\mathcal P_t$ on all of $\Gamma(E)$. Indeed, consider $\sigma\in\Gamma(E)$ and choose $\mathcal P_t(\sigma)$ so that for any $p\in M$ in the above notations we have $\mathcal P_t(\sigma)_{\theta_t(p)}=P_t(\sigma_p)$. Evidently, $\mathcal P_{-t}=\mathcal P_t^{-1}$. Furthermore, the identity $$\left.\frac d{dt}P_t^{-1}(\sigma_{\theta_t(p)})\right|_{t=0}=\nabla_X(\sigma)_p$$ can now be rewritten as $\frac d{dt}\mathcal P_{-t}|_{t=0}=\nabla_X$. The latter is an identity between linear operators on $\Gamma(E)$ and to compute the derivative one considers the pointwise (i.e. section-wise) convergence topology on $\mathrm{End}(\Gamma(E))$ induced by the pointwise convergence topology on $\Gamma(E)$.

**Question.** Is there anything inherently wrong with the above? If not, where can one find this approach of viewing parallel transport as an operator on the space of sections?

My second point is that in these terms one may obtain the formula for the Riemannian curvature operator. To me the below computation is a more convincing (or at least more precise) version of the usual hand-waving argument concerning the holonomy around an "infinitesimal parallelogram".

Choose vector fields $X$ and $Y$ both satisfying the above assumption and let $\mathcal P_t$ and $\mathcal Q_t$ be the corresponding operators on $\Gamma(E)$. Then, if we denote $\mathcal P_t=1+A(t)$ and $\mathcal Q_t=1+B(t)$, it is not hard to check that $$\left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t\partial s}\mathcal P_t^{-1}\mathcal Q_s^{-1}\mathcal P_t\mathcal Q_s\right|_{s=t=0}=\dot A(0)\dot B(0)-\dot B(0)\dot A(0)=\nabla_X\nabla_Y-\nabla_Y\nabla_X.$$ Note that this holds regardless of whether $X$ and $Y$ commute, i.e. whether the integral curves form a closed loop!

Finally, if we assume that $[X,Y]$ also satisfies the assumption and denote the corresponding operators by $\mathcal R_t$, we get $$\left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t\partial s}\mathcal R_{ts}\mathcal P_t^{-1}\mathcal Q_s^{-1}\mathcal P_t\mathcal Q_s\right|_{s=t=0}=\nabla_X\nabla_Y-\nabla_Y\nabla_X-\nabla_{[X,Y]}$$ so precisely the Riemannian curvature operator. The additional leftmost factor corresponds to the intuition of needing to correct by moving along $[X,Y]$ for time $ts$ to try to close the loop.

**Question.** Is there a mistake in this? If not, are such computations written out somewhere?

Comment: I've seen a similar description of curvature in Needham's "Visual Differential Geometry and Forms". But unfortunately, no rigorous proof.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Thank you, I had a look but I believe this logic of transporting entire sections instead of just fiber elements is not discussed there? Or did I miss it? To me the main advantage of this is that it allows to compute derivatives even when the "parallelogram" or the "pentagon" are not closed.

Comment: For the first half it feels like you are just doing the usual thing of differentiating along curves but now with an entire family of curves thrown in. Of course, you are developing it for the sake of the second half. But I feel confused about the final paragraph: it is not clear to me (a) Why $\mathcal{R}_{ts}$ (why time $ts$ is the correct amount) and (b) What happens when both partials fall on $\mathcal{R}_{ts}$?

Comment: Re (a) in my previous comment: one of the ways the $\nabla_{[X,Y]}$ term is justified is by requiring that the Riemann tensor be tensorial; as you mentioned, another way is to insist that the formula works only for commuting $X,Y$ and then extending it to the general case (essentially by tensoriality). Is there a way to connect this to your $\mathcal{R}_{ts}$?

Comment: @WillieWong Concerning your first comment: $\mathcal R_{ts}$ is the natural correcting factor from a Lie-theoretic standpoint. A way to define the Lie bracket is that following the flows of $X$ and $Y$ around "the parallelogram" agrees up to order 2 with following the flow of $[X,Y]$ for time $ts$, i.e. the map $\theta^{[X,Y]}_{ts}(\theta^X_t)^{-1}(\theta^Y_s)^{-1}\theta^X_t\theta^Y_s$ has a zero second differential. But I'm not sure I follow (b): "fall" means vanish? Why would that be an issue?

Comment: @WillieWong Concerning you second comment: yes, the fact that the commutator term ensures tensoriality in the case of non-commuting $X$ and $Y$ is the explanation I've seen. I suppose you can see why I find this... somewhat unsatisfactory.

Comment: @IgorMakhlin I am not sure I follow. Why does $\partial^2_{ts}\mathcal{R}_{ts}$ vanish?

Comment: @WillieWong But $\partial^2_{ts}\mathcal R_{ts}$ does not vanish, it equals $-\nabla_{[X,Y]}$. This is essentially the formula right below the first displayed equation.

Comment: @IgorMakhlin: evidently I am misreading what you wrote when you said "fall means vanish". But your final comment is helpful; I was missing your point a bit and that cleared it up. Thanks.

Comment: @WillieWong I was just literally asking if in the context of partial derivatives "to fall" means "to vanish" or something else =) But I'm glad that the confusion was cleared up at least somewhat.

Comment: Ah! We had a problem of miscommunication. I meant fall as in: "When taking $\partial^2_{xy} (AB)$, there is one term where both partials fall on $A$ (as in $\partial^2_{xy}A \cdot B$, one term where both partials fall on $B$, and two terms with one partial falling on $A$ and $B$ each."